# iOS view in bounds of another view

Tags: ios, uiview

I'm trying to implement a check if a view is bounds of another view to do something. This my code:

```
CGRect movingView = [self.viewController.view convertRect:recognizer.view.frame toView:self.viewController.view];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < arrayOfViewsToCheck.count; i++)
{
    UIView *view = resultArray [0];

    CGRect boxframe = [self.viewController.view convertRect:view.frame toView:self.viewController.view];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(movingView.frame, view.frame) )
    {
        isInBounds = YES;
    }
}
```

But when I execute my code and for example I have this two views:

```
(CGRect) $6 = origin=(x=569, y=513) size=(width=76, height=100)

(CGRect) $7 = origin=(x=358, y=520) size=(width=116, height=100)
```

are in bounds of each other but of each I don't know what I'm doing wrong because it seems like they are not on my code.

I'll really appreciate if can please let me know what I'm doing wrong trying to detect if the views are in bounds of each other

Comment: Those rectangles do not intersect.

Comment: Where are 'movingView' and 'boxframe' used?  The code is a little hard to follow because the variable names seem inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `CGRectIntersectsRect` is correct, but the rectangles in your example do not actually intersect. Here's what they look like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(569,513,76,100);
    CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(368,520,116,100);

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect2];

    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];
}
```

[image: non-intersecting rectangles]

And with a slightly modified version:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(469,513,76,100); /* Note 469 instead of 569 */
    CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(368,520,116,100);

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect1];
    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect2];

    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    [self.view addSubview:view1];
    [self.view addSubview:view2];

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2) ) {
        NSLog(@"Yay we intersect!");
    }
}
```

[image]